# Change the test root path/pattern in IntelliJ/PhpStorm

Tags: intellij-idea, namespaces, phpstorm, phpunit

In my PhpStorm/IntelliJ I have a `src` folder and a `test` folder (marked correctly as this in project settings).

My src files look like this for example:

```
path: src/Project/Module/Business/Customer/Model.php
namespace: Project\Module\Business\Customer
```

Already given by the application there is the following structure for tests:

```
path: tests/ProjectTest/Module/Business/Customer/ModelTest.php
namespace: ProjectTest\Module\Business\Customer
```

As you can see, instead of the same namespace structure under tests, the Namespace unfortunately begins with "ProjectTest".

The problem: Whenever I want to automatically create a test out of the source class it uses the wrong path like this:

```
path: tests/Project/Module/Business/Customer/ModelTest.php
namespace: Project\Module\Business\Customer
```

and I have to correct that manually. This extra effort makes the "automatically create a test file" useless for me.

Is it possible to say IntelliJ/PhpStorm that it should use "ProjectTest" instead of "Project" for tests?

How to solve this?

I found this article https://blog.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/2014/04/psr-0-psr-4-and-sourcetest-root-support-in-phpstorm-8-eap/ but I can't figure out if this applicable for my use case. I didn't have success with this, but maybe someone can give me a hint.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I'm aware it's not yet possible (at least for PHPUnit and PHPSpec):

Watch these tickets (star/vote/comment) to get notified on any progress:

- PHPUnit: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-38128
- PHPSpec: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-37910

Also check related tickets as well.

Answer (score 0):

How to solve it? Well first of all, but this might be subjective, you could use the same namespace. In my understanding the tests belong therein but I also know that others do this differently. I don't think so because this would probably fix your problem but by design - the tests are part of the project.

Regardless of the question of how to name the root name in a namespace for tests, I can also suggest to support that namespace in the `composer.json` file for `autoload-dev`.

Phpstorm has composer support and can read out the namespaces root and map it to the concrete directories which it otherwise could not. I can not tell you if this actually solves your problem, however it's not wrong to have it defined in your projects *Composer* file and otherwise check the PSR root paths of your IDE so that namespace mapping to directories is set up properly.

---

- [Appointing a default composer.json in a PhpStorm project (Phpstorm 2019.1 Help)](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/using-the-composer-dependency-manager.html#default_composer_json) - Jetbrains Phpstorm description which PSR roots can by synchronized and how it affects the IDE configuration

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. Like i said, the namespace is given by the existing project. I can't change it at all. Does configuring composer files change any behavior of the IDE?

Comment: @JimPanse: In Phpstorm configuring composer files does. There are built in options for that in the recent versions and there is also an extension for composer. I can also recommend to have the project well defined in the composer.json as it is a good place for your projects meta-data. I really can recommend it, I can't guarantee you it solves your problem, but for example for the namespaces, the IDE reads the namespace roots out of it, so you don't have to manually configure the IDE as well. - I added a link to Phpstorm help that provides more info about the built-in feature.